# Glossaries package is not showing symbols

Tags: symbols, packages, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am actually writing my master thesis on a latex template and I would like to make a glossary entry as "O&M". but the and symbol is not showing up. I have tried different approaches such as:

```
\& 
$&$
\ensuremath{&}
```

But none of them work. In the template I have there was the obsolete glossary package and I changed it with the more actual glossaries. There is my preamble:

```
\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries}
```

I hope someon can fix this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  AFAIK, `\&` should work, but without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) , I can't really test it to make sure it works in your specific case.

Comment: @PeterGrill Though it may not work as the key for the acronym.

Comment: @cfr: Perhaps. That's what the  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) would clarify.

Comment: If your template is using a package that was made obsolete in 2007, you might want to consider using a more modern template. If even you have managed to update it to using `glossaries` instead, it's likely that there's other obsolete code in it.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{O+M}{name={O\&M},description={whatever}}

\begin{document}
\gls{O+M}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: O&M. Glossary O&M whatever]

And so does this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{O+M}{O\&M}{O and M}

\begin{document}
\gls{O+M}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: O and M (O&M). Glossary O&M O and M]

As mentioned in the comments, special characters like `&` can't be used in the label, so I've used `+` instead. The label is just an identifier and doesn't affect the display.